# Copy/paste charts as pictures

Tags: excel, vba

> Error:The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type

I have an Excel file, with VBA Code. This file opens lots of other excel files and gets cell ranges and charts /as pictures/ to paste them in its sheets. This code is a part of a Sub that opens the source excel file, copy the chart from the source file and paste it in the workbook with the VBA code.

```
wsheetSource.ChartObjects(chart1Name).CopyPicture
wsheet.Range(char1Pos).PasteSpecial
wsheet.Pictures(wsheet.Pictures.Count).Name = chart1Name 'gives name of the last pasted picture
Set shp = wsheet.Shapes(chart1Name)
shp.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue


wsheetSource.ChartObjects(chart2Name).CopyPicture
wsheet.Range(char2Pos).PasteSpecial
wsheet.Pictures(wsheet.Pictures.Count).Name = chart2Name 'gives name of the last pasted picture
Set shp = wsheet.Shapes(chart2Name)
shp.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
```

The error: when I run this Sub couple of times, on copyPicture or PasteSpecial method, there's a message for error:
Run-time error '-2147221040 (800401d0)':
The specified dimension is not valid for the cirrent chart type

When I click Debug and run the problem line again, the code copies/paste the chart. I don't know what condition should be done to occurs this error. I think that the problem is with the clipboard /because in a few second I make lots of copy/paste operations/, tried to clear the clipboard, when the Sub starts, but with no success . 
how to avoid this error /the big question: why sometimes there's an error, sometimes-no/
Is there a way to add statement as: if on this line of code you have error, try to execute this line again /as I mentioned: if I click debug, go to the problem line and click Play button, the code start running/

BR

Comment: Which line of code is highlighted when you get the error message?

Comment: @JonPeltier
I get the error on copypicture or pastespecial.
The error can occurs on first copypicture, or the last pastespecial... It's a little bit random...

Comment: I've had this kind of error in the past, sporadic and frustrating, with equally meaningless error messages. But to try it out before I posted my comment above, I ran a sample routine that did CopyPicture and PasteSpecial 50 times, and no errors occurred.